# Is there a way to use the Sonar Squid check with Checkstyle independently?

Tags: squid, checkstyle, sonarqube

We would like to get statistics like number of non commenting statements, number of classes, number of methods.  JavaNCSS doesn't work with generics in many situations.  I'm wondering if i can just use Sonar Squid specifically the CheckstyleSquidBridge class and plugin that in as a module to Checkstyle 5.1.  And this would be independent of using full blown Sonar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is unhappily not possible.